# How to add token validation only for protected actions in ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: authentication, oauth, asp.net-core, jwt, openid-connect

I have added a JWT middleware to my application:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options => { options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;} )
```

Now if my token does not validate (e.g. expired), I still get an error that lifetime validation did not pass. Is there a way to make the middleware validate the token only for protected resources? And if not, then how and where should I call what middleware does myself (reading the token into HttpContext.User)?

P.S This is how I add protection:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();

    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

And this is how I allow public access:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public string Get(int id)
{
}
```

To clarify: without the token this will work, but if the token is not valid (e.g. expired) even the public resource won't be accessible and 500 will be thrown (due to some internal bug cause 401 should be there really).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to disable automatic authentication by setting **AutomaticAuthentication** to *false* in your JWT bearer options.

To ensure the JWT bearer middleware is called for specific actions, you can create your own authorization policy using **AddAuthenticationSchemes**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddAuthorization(options => {
        options.AddPolicy("API", policy => {
            policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        });
    });
}
```

Then, decorate your controller actions with the `Authorize` attribute:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "API")]
[HttpGet("your-action")]
public IActionResult Action() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did not quite understand how this will help... I already have a filter to add RequireAuthenticatedUser for all [Authorize] attribute, but the problem is not that I can access protected resources, but the opposite: I cannot access public resources (when token is expired), because it seems that the jwt token validation happens in any case, regardless of the resource being protected or not... I will add a bit more code to the question

Comment: Configuring an authorization policy is the recommended way to enable manual authentication (aka passive authentication in Katana). Of course, you'll need to turn AutomaticAuthenticate off to prevent the JWT bearer middleware from being called automatically (I thought it was obvious but I'll update my answer to mention it).

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try. But I did not quite get what triggers the parsing of token in this case if automatic auth is turned off? And another question if this approach is possible to use with filter, i.e. will AllowAnonymous override the Authorize policy to skip the check?

Comment: In this case, authentication will be triggered by MVC's authorization filter (before the authorization rules are applied). Defining AuthorizeFilter at the global level won't help as it will still trigger the buggy JWT middleware for all your MVC actions, even if you decorate them with AloowAnonymous: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/AuthorizeFilter.cs#L53

Comment: Why would I need the jwt middleware then? Or the only reason is that it will register the bearer scheme that will further be used by authorize attribute? If I understand you correctly, there is no way to fully protect all API by default with the filter and allow anonymous access only to some (I guess the only way is not to send the token at all from the client side for known api)

Comment: You still need the JWT middleware to use token authentication (it won't work at all if you don't add it). To answer your last remark, of course it's possible. But as you mentioned, there's a big bug in RC1 that prevents this scenario and that's why you need to disable automatic authentication and re-enable it on specific (else, it will be invoked everywhere and cause 500 exceptions)

Comment: I thought the bug only does 500 instead of 401. So you say that if it's fixed (in RC2 hopefully), then the middleware will work properly even with automaticauthentication = true (it will respect authorize/allow anonymous) and I won't need any workarounds. I really hope this is how it will work in next versions :)

Comment: Yes, it's fixed in RC2 ;)

Comment: I guess, I'll just not pass the token from the client for now and wait until it's fixed, hopefully it's released soon. Thank you very much for your help!