# Self Hosted Asp Net Core Web server, client authentication with self-signed certificates

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, kestrel-http-server, ssl-client-authentication

I am testing a self-hosted Asp Net Core Web server (Kestrel), and I am struggling with the client authentication using self-signed certificates.
This is my startup code

```
WebApplicationBuilder webBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
var webHostBuilder = builder.WebHost;

X509Certificate2 rootCert = new X509Certificate2(hostCertFilePath, hostCertPassword);

webHostBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
{
    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
    {
        o.ServerCertificate = rootCert;
        o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
    });
});

webHostBuilder.UseKestrel(o =>
{
    o.Listen(IPAddress.Parse(myHttpsEndPointIpAddr), myHttpsEndPointPort,
        listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.UseHttps();
        });
    o.Listen(IPAddress.Parse(myHttpEndPointIpAddr), myHttpEndPointPort);
});

var services = webBuilder.Services;

services.AddTransient<MyCustomCertificateValidationService>();
services
    .AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.SelfSigned;
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                    .GetService<MyCustomCertificateValidationService>();

                if (validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
                {
                    context.Success();
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Fail("invalid cert");
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                context.Fail("invalid cert");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

...

var app = webBuilder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

This my custom certification class

```
public class MyCustomCertificateValidationService
{
    public bool ValidateCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
    {
        // todo: check certificate thumbnail
        return false;
    }
}
```

But even if MyCustomCertificateValidationService has a method ValidateCertificate() that returns false, the controller method is still called when a client accesses the url with the route to the controller method.
This is what is displayed in the log:

```
...
AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware : Request matched endpoint ‘GetMyData…‘
AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate.CertificateAuthenticationHandler : Certificate was not authenticated. Failure message: invalid cert
AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware : Executing endpoint ‘GetMyData…‘
...
```

Any clue why the controller method is still called?

Comment: Why are you wanting to use client-side certificates?

Comment: What do you mean? The server has a root certificate, and the clients get client certificates generated from root.

Comment: I'm curious why you chose that approach considering the relative difficulty involved compared to other approaches for client authentication (e.g. OAuth2's `client_credentials`) or even HTTP Basic Auth...

Comment: Your `ValidateCertificate` returns false! Of course that leads to: `"Certificate was not authenticated. Failure message: invalid cert"`.

Comment: Yes, it returns false on purpose. I would expect that the client receives a validation error response without body content, instead of Status Code 200 and the body with the response to the request. I want to test the use-case when the server does not validate the client access. The web-server has to use certificates, it is a customer requirement to use SSL mutual authentication for the application.

Comment: Did you place [Authorize] attribute on your controller/method?

Comment: You are right, the [Authorize] attribute was missing, now it works as expected! Is it possible to set the equivalent of the [Authorize] attribute programmatically, for all controllers ? There is a use-case for the application that in some test environment also unauthorized calls (over http://...) should be allowed. I would prefer to use, if possible, a settings parameter to decide dynamically if http access is allowed or not, instead of "hardcode" it as [Authorize] attribute

Comment: This answer will likely help solve your comment question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59645530/5517088

Answer (score 0):

> "There is a use-case for the application that in some test environment
> also unauthorized calls (over http://...) should be allowed. I would
> prefer to use, if possible, a settings parameter to decide dynamically
> if http access is allowed or not, instead of "hardcode" it as
> [Authorize] attribute"

Of course you can do that. There is a handy way to implement your requirement using **middleware** for sure. Please try the code snippe below:

**Http/Https Request Middleare Based On Environment:**

```
public class CustomHttpHttpsRequestMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        public CustomHttpHttpsRequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
                //env = "Production";
            if (env == "Development")
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!context.Request.IsHttps)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("HTTPS required!");
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

**Note:** In application `request context` we are checking two important value, first if the request is secure means `cIsHttps` and the `application environment`, in `Development` environment we will allow `http` request. Therefore, other than, `dev` or any `env` based on our requirement we will reject `http` request.

**Register Middleware on Program.cs:**

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<CustomHttpHttpsRequestMiddleware>();
```

**Note:** Make sure you have followed the correct middleware order. In order to avoid short circuiting, you could place this middleware way down of your all current middleware.

**Output:**

[image]